# subtraction in a php while loop

Tags: php, loops, subtraction

I'd like to think I'm far from a PHP novice, but for some reason I cannot get the following to work. I'm trying to subtract a value from a number using a PHP while loop.

The code is below, but it only seems to be subtracting the first value.

I've obviously initiated a mysql query, and then have the following code:

```
 $scMins = 500;
 while($f=mysql_fetch_object($r)){

  $duration = $f->duration;

  $scRem = ($scMins - $duration);


 }


 return $scRem;
```

but its just notn working.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 3):

You always subtract from the initial value scMins

```
$scRem = 500;
while($f=mysql_fetch_object($r)){
  $duration = $f->duration;
  $scRem = ($scRem - $duration);
}
```

Comment: I'm being an absolute idiot today. I'm tired - thats why. This makes perfect sense and worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is $r?

If it returns nothing, then it most likely means that your loop is wrong. I'd check if your query actually returns something (or if it errors), the problem most likely lies there.

Answer (score 0):

In your while-loop the variables $scRem gets overwritten at each iteration. Try

```
$scRem += ($scMins - $duration);
```

But honestly it's not very clear what you are trying to achive, so this may be the wrong answer ;-)